# Why in app product purchase in Google Play is automatically refunded?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

After updating the app billing lib to 
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1'
I started to see refunds even after 3 days. How is that possible? Google only mentions [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=pl) that purchse is refunded if user uninstall the app in short period after purchase. I guess 3 days is not a short period.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Users must acknowledge the purchase within 3 days otherwise the subscription will be refunded:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge

Answer (score 5):

Do the following in **PurchasesUpdatedListener**

```
private val purchaseUpdateListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
for (purchase in purchases) {
    if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                 val acknowledgePurchaseParams = 
                     AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                     .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken).build()

                 billingClient?.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams) { 
                     billingResult ->
                         val billingResponseCode = billingResult.responseCode
                         val billingDebugMessage = billingResult.debugMessage

                         Log.v("TAG_INAPP", "response code: $billingResponseCode")
                         Log.v("TAG_INAPP", "debugMessage : $billingDebugMessage")
                        }
         }
 }
```

This code will send confirmation of the purchase to the google servers. So any purchase made from your app won't be invalid anymore and won't be refunded automatically.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)